# Python C-extension class with a dynamic size

Tags: python, c++, c, segmentation-fault, python-c-extension

I try to write C-extension which contains python class.

This class takes a filename as a parameter **`fname`** of constructor, then loads that file to memory and stores as a config.

Below what I have:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    XmlConfig m_cfg;
} PyAgent;

static int PyAgent_init(PyAgent *self, PyObject *args) {
    const char *fname;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &fname)) {
    return NULL;
    }
    self->m_cfg.Load(fname);
    return 0;
}

static PyTypeObject PyAgentType = {
   PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
   0,                                            /* ob_size */
   "classify.Agent",                             /* tp_name */
   ...
}
...
```

I get segmentation fault when I try to load file. As I understand it happens because **`PyAgent struct`** has object size that increases because of memory allocation for file.

I've tried to use **`PyObject_VAR_HEAD`** macro but it doesn't help.

Can you give a clue or working similar example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `self->m_cfg` needs to be initialized first?  You are calling a C++ method on it, but didn't call its constructor first.  The struct is allocated by C code, not C++, so it doesn't know it needs to construct this field.

There are ways to manually call the constructor (something like `new(&self->m_cfg) XmlConfig()` if I remember correctly), but the easiest is probably to have instead a field `XmlConfig *cfg`, and allocate and free it as needed with the usual syntax of the C++ operators `new` and `delete` (the latter to be put in the `tp_dealloc`).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've chosen the easiest way with `new`/`delete`.